# One bookmark for all pages in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

In Spotfire, we can create Bookmark it takes snapshot of current active page or Active Visualization and save it. Suppose we have n number of pages in Spotfire analysis then if we need to take a snapshot of each and every page then we have to create separate bookmark for each one. 
I am finding a way to create bookmark for several pages/visualizations, but not getting anything. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bookmark snapshots the entire dxp (analysis), not just the active page or visualization. Thus, if you create a bookmark and then make changes on multiple pages (filtering, row selections, etc) the bookmark will revert all changes. They are saved per user, per **document**.

> A bookmark can capture one or more of the following: specific rows you
>   have marked, active pages and visualizations, and even specific
>   filtering that you have applied. A bookmark also contains information
>   about visualization properties such as what column was used on an
>   axis, what column was used to color by, etc., as well as any custom
>   property values you have used on the active page. You decide what
>   should be included in a captured state, but a bookmark that is added
>   without making any adjustments will automatically include all those
>   parts in the bookmark

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, as you said bookmark can capture active pages and visulizations. I tried same but it capture active page( page which is opened/active ) and visualizations from that page.. not All active pages.

Comment: I tested this and it works as I explained. If you ADD a page after the bookmark it won't work.

Comment: No I already have pages like(page1, page2, page3), I am on page1 and creating bookmark then its only capture active page visualizations, not from page2 and page3,
Note: I am using spotfire6.5

Comment: What are you doing on page 2 and 3 (what are you changing) that isn't getting changed back?

Comment: I am limiting data  using  expression like "[country]=india" in all pages and creating bookmark "india".. repeating same steps like US, Canada.
when I open "india" Bookmark then it only reflects to the page where I was while creating it. other pages does not.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a limitation of Bookmarks, similarly to filtering out marked rows. What you are trying to do is exactly what filtering is for. As long as each page has the same filtering scheme, clicking the "India" filter on one page will filter all other pages as well.

Comment: Means the way I am doing it will not work for all pages.Thanks for you time and help.